# `unoconv` not exporting all content of an excel sheet to pdf

Tags: unoconv

I am using this command to convert .XLSX file to PDF.
`/usr/bin/unoconv -vvv -f pdf -o test.pdf 'somename.xlsx'`

So pdf is generating successfully, but when I checked the pdf content, It was missing contents from one sheet.

I am not sure why it is missing content. It will be helpful If someone guide me to troubleshoot.

Comment: would be interesting to know which type of content was missing.
Was it formulas, or plain text, some special formatting?

Comment: @Sunchezz, basically it is missing complete sheets to export, I have 7 sheets in one section, and it is only showing 3 out of 7 in the PDF file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is due to older version install of openoffice on centos server, after installing the updated version of openoffice, it is working fine.

Comment: what version of OpenOffice (or is it LibreOffice) is that? I still can't get multiple sheets to render as CSV here, and it seems unclear whether or not this is fixed in unoconv: https://github.com/unoconv/unoconv/issues/198